# Reference to dependent assembly in XML Comments

Tags: c#, .net, xml-comments

I have 2 class libraries projects **A** and **B**, and **A** depends on (has a reference to) **B**.

In **B** I have a class to which I want to add XML comments, and mention a class in **A** using a `<see cref="ClassInA"/>`. The problem is that because **B** doesn't have a reference to **A** (only vice versa), then I get a warning:

`CS1574: C# XML comment has cref attribute that could not be resolved`

Is there a way to somehow "add a reference" but only for XML Comments purposes?

**Clarification:**

Project A contains an interface A.I and a method that takes A.I as an argument. Project B contains a default implementation of A.I, that should be used in most cases. In the comment I want to specify that in most cases you should pass the default implementation defined in B. But because B have dependencies on other libraries that in some cases are not desirable then the default implementation shouldn't be in A.

Comment: If you want to do this, then you're thinking back to front. `B` should **never** know about `A`, even in comments.

Comment: You'll have to write the comment as text. From a systems design point of view I agree with @DavidG, and following his thought that B should not know about A it seems awkward (at best) to have a "hard" link to the class that is defined in A in the comments.

Comment: @DavidG: I added a clarification why I need this and still believe that my design is correct.

Comment: What you describe is impossible though. If `B` contains a class that implements an interface inside `A`, then `B` requires a reference to `A`. You say the reference is the other way round which would make it circular and wouldn't even build.

Comment: I guess you're right. I was hoping that there's some kind of way to specify a reference inside the XML comment or through some sort of configuration which is not part of the regular project references. Apparently there's no such thing, and I have to describe it as a regular text.